# Need help taking away opacity on scrolling menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to find a way to take away the opacity on the sticky menu to our FRC Robotics website (www.rambotics4573.club) My teammates that are also helping create the website find it annoying that that scrolling portion remains barely transparent. Can I use a simple CSS plugin with some code, or would I go into our theme files and edit the code directly from there?
Thanks in advance!

I've tried finding the snippets of code on the menu, no luck though.

Comment: Please share code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this style:

```
background-color:rgba(127,38,38,0.9);
```

by:

```
background-color: rgba(127,38,38);
```

Comment: More specifically: `.site-header.header-scrolled { background-color:rgba(127,38,38)}`